# How do i deploy fast to firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I recently started working at a startup that uses Firebase as their backend and the main developer left before I started on the backend portion of the app. After some time I understood how I deploy functions and how to work with  Firebase. For that, I make my changes in the index.js file and then run the command  `Firebase deploy --only functions`. The problem is it takes a lot of time for these functions to get deployed, even when all I change is one variable. My question is, is this how you work with firebase, isn't there a faster way to deploy? I searched a bit but can't seem to find anything, I thought maybe the Firebase emulator could help but I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For development, the expected flow is to use the local emulator (docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite ).

You run it from your project directory with `firebase emulators:start` and it hot reloads local changes.

You visit `localhost:5000` to view hosting changes, and `localhost:4001` for function logs (both ports are customizable).